# How do I stop the re-rendering of my react component? It rerenders for every object in a drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After building the homepage of my website I finally figured out how to dynamically navigate to other pages. I wanted the browser to render the State homepage when a user clicked on a dropdown and selected a state. The navigation works, but it re-renders the component 50 times which I do not understand. I suspect it is due to the map function that is creating the menuitems. I could build out 50 individual menuitems but that is really ugly.

I am just starting out learning React. I have 7 YRS experience in backend development, but I am still trying to get a handle on React development. I have created a wepage with Material UI that has a dropdown that looks like this

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel>Select a State</InputLabel>
  <Select value={location} onChange={selectionChangeHandler}>
    {locations.map((value) => (
     <MenuItem value={value.toLowerCase()} key={value.toLowerCase()} component={Link} to={`${value.toLowerCase()}/home`} >
      {value}
     </MenuItem> 
    ))}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

This returns a dropdown with the 50 states in it. When the user clicks on a state I want the program to route to that page on click. This dynamic routing works BUT. It re-renders my component 50 times. I think this is happening because the dropdown is being built inside of a .map functions and there are 50 entries in that list.

I can remove the map function and hardcode in 50 menuitems but that is ugly.

Here is my onChange Function

```
const selectionChangeHandler = (event) => {
console.log(event.target.value) 
}
```

I have also tried removing the component={Link} and using the useNavigate hook in the selectionChangeHandler like so

```
const selectionChangeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setlocation(event.target.value)
    link = `${event.target.value}/home`
    navigate(link)

  }
```

This works but also renders 50 times. I am at a loss.

I cross posted the above to reddit and then I researched a little more. It turns out in React. When a parent component's state is updated it re-renders all child components. This may be what is going on here, but I do not know how to fix it. Even if I pass the state as a prop to the child component I still have to link to the correct page.

I am kind of nervous about posting I really tried to put work into solving my own problem before reaching out for help, and I might be reaching out for help a lot as I learn. I am committed to learning, but some problems I just cannot figure out on my own.

Link to Code [Link to Code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/de7h81bvu9a4qfc/src.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share your code? Can't find out actual issue with the provided code.

Comment: Just shared the code thank you for being willing to assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is inside `StateHome.js`. You use a naked `axios.get` call directly in your component so it's going to re-render anytime the component changes from state change.

When you get the results you set state inside the same component  which re-renders the component, which then re-runs the axios.get call, causing the loop.

I understand you want to call that endpoint when someone lands on the `/alabama/home` page. To tell `React` "Do this one time when the component loads" you must use a `useEffect` *with an empty dependency array*. So instead of this:

```
const StateHome = () => {
  const { location } = useParams();
  const [PageData, SetPageData] = useState();
  axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/${location}/home`).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.statusText);
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.config);
    SetPageData(response.data);
  });
  return <h1>This is my State Home Page Component for State {location}</h1>;
};
```

You need to use this:

```
const StateHome = () => {
  console.log("StateHome");
  const { location } = useParams();
  const [PageData, SetPageData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/${location}/home`).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.statusText);
      console.log(response.headers);
      console.log(response.config);
      SetPageData(response.data);
    });
  }, []); // <--- indicates "on mount", loads once regadless of other side-effects (setState)
  
  return <h1>This is my State Home Page Component for State {location}</h1>;
};
```

Comment: Even after I completely eliminate the use of state in my component I still re-render 50 times. I am at complete loss for why this is happening. I too thought it was because I was setting state but that is not the reason why. It must have to do with the use of OnChange. Something to do with the .map and OnChange is making me re-render 50 times.

Comment: I found the issue to be relating to how you call Axios in one of your other components - revising my answer.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much when I was doing react to the classes I would use a component did mount. For some reason I assumed that because I was going from one component to the other it would only run on the click of the drop-down and it wouldn't run with every change.